# Is there a way to disable the right-to-left-stroke-to-delete-gesture in Google handwriting input?

Tags: text-input, google-japanese-input

I couldn’t find any option in *settings* to disable the right-to-left-stroke-to-delete-gesture in Google (Japanese) handwriting input. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bud, but this is Google's new keyboard. In the earlier versions you simply had to tap the backspace key once to erase your previously Swyped word but in the newer versions you have to swipe right to left.